# Matlab plot is missing corner value in plot when using comma as a decimal

Tags: matlab

To change the decimal from . to , on the x-axis and y-axis from the plot I use this function:

```
function decimal_comma(axis_handle, axis_name, varargin)

  switch axis_name
    case 'XY'
        decimal_comma(axis_handle, 'X', varargin{:});
        decimal_comma(axis_handle, 'Y', varargin{:});

    case {'X', 'Y'}
        tick = get(axis_handle, strcat(axis_name, 'Tick'));

        n = length(tick);
        labels = cell(1,n);

        for i = 1:n
            label = num2str(tick(i), varargin{:});
            labels{i} = strrep(label, '.', ',');
        end

        labels{1} = '';
        labels{n} = '';

        set(axis_handle, strcat(axis_name, 'TickLabel'), labels);

    otherwise
        error('Wrong axis name! Use one of X, Y or XY.');
  end
end
```

my plot function :

```
data = load ('w3.mat');
plot(data.w3(:,1), data.w3(:,5),'g',data.w3(:,1), data.w3(:,4),'k'...
,data.w3(:,1), data.w3(:,7),'m')
hold on
x1 = data.w3(:,1);
y1 = data.w3(:,5);
y2 = data.w3(:,4);
y3 = data.w3(:,7);
err1 = 0.009*ones(size(y1));
err2 = 0.009*ones(size(y2));
err3 = 0.018*ones(size(y3));
errorbar(x1, y1, err1,'Color','green');
errorbar(x1, y2,err2,'Color','black');
errorbar(x1, y3, err3, 'Color','magenta');
lgd = legend('transmissie','reflectie','samen','Location','west','Orientation','verticol');   
title(lgd,'Legenda')
title('gefolariseerd onder 0 graden ')
xlabel('hoek van inval');
ylabel('intensiteit');
decimal_comma(gca, 'X', '%.0f');
decimal_comma(gca, 'Y', '%.1f');
```

When I run this function the following plot is shown

[image: The plot]

In this plot, the corner values are missing, I would like to make them visible and still have commas as a decimal in the axis.

Comment: You can manually specify the ticks. Refer [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the current (defaultized) `xticks` / `yticks` settings. You have to play with them in order to get corner tick marks. Alternatively, try to manipulate `xlim` and `ylim` values until you obtain a result that fit your needs.

Anyway, your method for changing the comma separators looks a bit tricky to me... I propose you the following one:

```
plot(x,y);
ax = gca;
ChangeDecimals(ax,'%.0f','X');
ChangeDecimals(ax,'%.1f','Y');

function ChangeDecimals(ca,fmt,opt)
    if (nargin < 1)
        ca = gca;
    end

    if (nargin < 2)
        fmt = '%.1f';
    end

    if (nargin < 3)
        opt = 'Both';
    end

    % reformat X-Axis ticks...
    if (strcmp(opt,'Both') || strcmp(opt,'X'))
        ticks = get(ca,'XTick'); 
        lbls = arrayfun(@(x){strrep(sprintf(fmt,x),'.',',')},ticks);
        set(ca,'XTickLabel',lbls);
    end

    % reformat Y-Axis ticks...
    if (strcmp(opt,'Both') || strcmp(opt,'Y'))
        ticks = get(ca,'YTick'); 
        lbls = arrayfun(@(x){strrep(sprintf(fmt,x),'.',',')},ticks);
        set(ca,'YTickLabel',lbls);
    end
end
```

Comment: but when i plot the graph whit this function i get  dots again instead of a comma.

Comment: You mean when you replot?

Comment: Of course. Well, immediately after your first plot function call (even before fixig your commans for the first time), add use this: ca = gca; addlistener(ca,'XLim','PostSet',@MyFun); addlistener(ca,'YLim','PostSet',@MyFun);